# Return highest number from a list of coded numbers

Tags: arcpy, python, vba

I'm trying to make a button in ArcMap that returns the highest number from a list of coded numbers we have for our manhole layer.

The structure of the coded values is as follows **"0010010001"**. This number is actually read as three distinct groupings of numbers, **"001-001-0001"**, where the first three numbers represent the lift station that a specific manhole dumps to, the second grouping of numbers refers to the specific section of said lift station, and the last four numbers are simply the manhole's unique number within that lift station section.

so for example, **"0130020135"**, read as **"013-002-0135"**, represents a manhole going to lift station **13**, in section **2**, and is the **135th** manhole in that section. The next new manhole in this area would have the number **0130020136**.

The tool should ask for the first 6 numbers, and then return the highest value of the **last 4** numbers already being used depending on the combination of the first **6** numbers, so that I know what to number each new manhole without manually searching through a list of values.

Comment: Hey, welcome to GIS SE. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are going for, but if the coded value is a string, you can use it as a list. So you can use the pattern to pull out each value: lift station, section, and manhole. You can use functions like int() to convert strings to numbers.

I might use a dictionary to track each manhole, using the ls and sec as keys, and store the manhole number as a list. The function max() will pull out the maximum value from a list.

```
coded = "0130020135"
ls = coded[:3]
section = coded[3:6]
mh = coded[6:]
mh_int = int(mh)

coded_dict = {}
coded_dict[ls]={section:[mh_int]}
max(coded_dict[ls][section])
```